# Delete a column and a row in a square matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix

I had a square matrix typed dynamically, correctly allocated

```
double **matrix;
```

I want to delete a "x" row and "x" column from that matrix, in a way like that:

```
SOURCE MATRIX:
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

I want to remove, for example, the 2nd row/column. The output had to be like this:

```
FINAL MATRIX:
1 3 4
9 11 12
13 15 16
```

I've tried to write down and test many algorithms, without success.
How can I do?

Comment: Do you have to do this in place or can you build another matrix?

Comment: It would be a total mess to do it in-place.

Comment: I prefer doing this in place :)

Comment: In fact it's way easier doing this with another matrix, but I need this matrix to implement graphs, so I think that with a very big graph, using another matrix to delete the old one takes a lot of space.

Comment: Just think that you have to shift rows/columns to a new place. It can end up with shifting almost whole matrix if the indices are small. So you will end up with same, or even greater complexity.

Comment: Unless you are coming up with some smarter data structure than just a 2D array, of course..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to do this, you'll have to realise that in memory your matrix is actually a *list of lists*. 
This means that removing a column is slightly different from removing a row:

Assuming your syntax is `matrix[row][column];`

```
void removeColumn(int** matrix, int col){
  MATRIX_WIDTH--;
  //TODO check for empty matrix etc;
  for(int i=0;i<MATRIX_HEIGHT; i++)
  {
    while(col<MATRIX_WIDTH)
    {
      //move data to the left
      matrix[i][col]=matrix[i][col+1];
      col++;
    }
  matrix[i] = realloc(matrix[i], sizeof(double)*MATRIX_WIDHT);
  }
void removeRow(int** matrix, int row){
  MATRIX_HEIGHT--;
  //TODO check for empty matrix etc.
  free(matrix[row]);
  while(row<MATRIX_HEIGHT)
  {
    //move data up
    matrix[row] = matrix[row+1];
    row++;
  }
}
```

so `removeColumn` iterates over each row, and deletes the appropriate item, and `removeRow` can just `free` the row, and overwrite its pointer.

NOTE that you have to keep track of the size of the matrix size yourself. In the example i used `MATRIX_WIDTH` and `MATRIX_HEIGHT` but you'll have to implement something for this. (Maybe a struct with width height and pointer in it.)

Comment: This algorithm works like a charm! It's efficient in time and space, and it does what I want. Thank you, you make my day :D

Comment: I'd prefer `memmove()` in place of each `while()` loop, e.g. replace `while(col < MATRIX_WIDTH) {}` with `memmove(matrix[i] + col, matrix[i] + col + 1, sizeof(int) * (MATRIX_WIDTH - col - 1))`. But if we're indulging preferences, I'd prefer to represent the matrix as a 1D array!

Comment: I tested well this algorithm and, so, it doesn't work as I wish. I had problem with columns.

For example: if I want to delete the first row and the first column, it deletes the first row but erase the LAST column.

Maybe there's problem when I call functions?

removeColumn((double **)G->adjK, node, G->num_nodes);
removeRow((double **)G->adjK, node, G->num_nodes);

I defined the function in this way, I thought it was the same thing

void removeColumn(double **matrix, int col, int dim);
void removeRow(double **matrix, int row, int dim);

Comment: Resolved: in the algorithm we have to reset "col" variable after every while.

Answer (score 0):

As I was looking for a answer to the similar problem but with matrix stored in linear space here's my solution (I'm using column-major order here, but if you're using row-major it only minor changes are needed)

```
void removeRow(float * arrayToRemove, const int & currentRows, const int & currentCols, const int & row)
{
    auto currDiff = 0;
    auto step = currentRows;
    auto elemNum = currentRows * currentCols;

    for (int i = row, stepCounter = 0; i < elemNum; ++i, ++stepCounter)
    {
        if (stepCounter % step == 0)
        {
            ++currDiff;
        }
        else
        {
            arrayToRemove[i - currDiff] = arrayToRemove[i];
        }
    }
}

void removeCol(float * arrayToRemove, const int & currentRows, const int & currentCols, const int & col)
{
    auto destination = arrayToRemove + (col * currentRows);
    auto source = arrayToRemove + ((col + 1) * currentRows);
    const auto elemsNum = (currentCols - (col + 1)) * currentRows;
    memcpy(destination, source, elemsNum * sizeof(float));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is split this matrix into 5 zones.
1) zone to be deleted. 2) Zone "before" the deleted index (it would be just 1 in your example matrix). 3) Zone "after" the deleted index (it would be 11,12,15,16 in your matrix). 4) and 5) Are the two remaining 'zones'. One would be (3, 4) the other would (9,13)

Just make a conditional for each of the 5 zones and copy.

```
double** matrix = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double)*n*n);
//fill in the matrix here
double** copy (double**)malloc(sizeof(double)*(n-1)*(n-1));
int i;
int j;
int deleteNum;  //what ever row you want to delete
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
        if(i < deleteNum && j < deleteNum){
            copy[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
        }
        else if(deleteNum == i || deleteNum == j){
             //one of the rows/columns to be deletd
             //basically skip
        }
        else if(i < deleteNum && j > deleteNum){
             copy[i][j-1] = matrix[i][j];
        }
        else if(i > deleteNum && j < deleteNum){
             copy[i-1][j] = matrix[i][j]
        }
        else{
            copy[i-1][j-1] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a matrix to implement a graph. There are (in my opinion) more benefits of using an adjacency list.

Comment: It depends on the application

Comment: Indeed, but it's for an University Exam :)

Comment: isn't the matrix in this situation just a single pointer like `double* `?